# xml file gets deleted unexpectedly on a GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, xml

I am reading text from a xml file, and insert this text into a Label. I read the text from the xml file every 5th second, in case it has changed. This mean that I insert the text into the label every 5th second (no matter if it has changed or not).
Now the problem is that my xml file gets deleted when I do a GET the 2nd time, and this results in a 500 (internal server error), since the file is no longer there.

Here is the code that creates the xml document

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public string GetMessage() {
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (Global.sAppPath + "/alt/importantMsg.xml");

    string message = null;

    while (reader.Read()) {
        if (reader.IsStartElement ()) {
            switch (reader.Name.ToString ()) {

            case "Message":
                message = reader.ReadString();
                break;
            }
        } 
    }       
    return message;
}
```

And here is the code that issues a GET

```
    window.setInterval(function() {
        msg;

        $.ajax({
            url: "isoServe.asmx/GetMessage",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                msg = data.d;
            },
            error: function() { 
                alert("Error");
            }
        }); 

        Ext.getCmp('attentionLabel').setText(msg);
        Ext.getCmp('attentionLabel').show();

}, 5000);
```

Below is the code that issues a POST, to save the message to the xml file, along with the client code

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddToXMLFile (string param)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today; 

    XmlNode rootNode = doc.CreateElement("Scant");
    XmlNode dateNode = doc.CreateElement("Date");
    XmlNode importantMsg = doc.CreateElement("Message");

    XmlAttribute msgId = doc.CreateAttribute("id");
    msgId.Value = "msgID";

    dateNode.InnerText = today.ToString();
    importantMsg.InnerText = param;
    importantMsg.Attributes.Append(msgId);

    rootNode.AppendChild(dateNode);
    rootNode.AppendChild(importantMsg);

    doc.AppendChild(rootNode);
    doc.Save(Global.sAppPath + "/alt/importantMsg.xml");
}
```

And the client code

```
 function saveMsg(msg) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "isoServe.asmx/AddToXMLFile", true); //async
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("param=" + msg);
}
```

Can anyone see why the xml file suddenly gets deleted, which results in an internal server error?

A piece of the error message shown in firebug is this:

```
Document element did not appear. file:///var/www/topix/alt/importantMsg.xml Line 1, position 1.","StackTrace":"
```

Comment: Are you sure it's deleted? If it was deleted you normally wouldn't get an error stating the Document element did not appear. That usually indicates something else. Can you see the file where it should be? Also, have you verified there weren't any errors in the creation of the file? None of this should delete the file so proper creation may be suspect.

Comment: Yes my bad. It's not the file beeing deleted, but the contents of it. The code does create a XML document as desired. But eventually it deletes the contents of the file.

Comment: `doc.Save(Global.sAppPath + "/alt/importantMsg.xml");` this line is overwriting your xml file with no content. Comment this line out and try again.

Comment: I will try that when I get back to that computer. But the strange thing is that, that part of code is only called when a button is clicked. And the code will still be overwritten, even when it's not beeing clicked. 

If I delete that line, is there an alternative to save the file? I will need to save it somehow